# Are there any hotkeys in dash for choosing among search term matches?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, unity-dash, files

Are there any hotkeys for dash, once a search term has been entered?
For example, if I would like to go to a folder very quickly I would want to press <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to open the dash and then type the name...

I then must type <kbd>tab</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> so that folders are chosen. Then I must hit <kbd>tab</kbd> again to get focus on the folder list!

Is there a hotkey for this searching only folders for example?

Comment: @Marco Ceppi: I disagree that this is a duplicate.  I think I should change the title so that it is clearly not a duplicate.  This question is about keys for navigating in the dash once a search term has been entered.

Comment: You don't need to hit tab. You can hit down three times instead, although that's slightly faster.

Comment: @pydave: i've tried this and it doesn't seem to be working.  remember, i want to have it only search folders.

Comment: not a keyboard friendly solution - but right click the Files & Folders lens and choose "Folders" - then obviously you will only be searching for folders.

Comment: I misunderstood. You're changing the search type not navigating the results. Tab, Down, Down accomplishes the same as what fossfreedom describes, but with the keyboard instead of the mouse.

Comment: BUMP.  The situation has gotten even more dire with the version of dash in 11.10.  Is there now no sequence of keys I can hit to reproduce the scenario in my question?

Answer (score 2):

You can hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing your query to launch the first match, you can also hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> in quick succession to launch the first thing it matches whether it renders it in the dash or not (sort of like "I'm feeling lucky").

As far as I can tell, that's currently the only shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a hotkey, but you could script searching for folders with [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) [image: Install Xdotool].

```
# invoke the files lens
xdotool key Super+f 
# wait for the dash to show
sleep 0.5s
# navigate the menu
xdotool key Tab Down Down Shift+Tab
```

You could save that as a bash script and then set a custom keyboard shortcut in CompizConfig Settings Manager. (See the Commands plugin.)